# Setting FabricIO key from Gradle: "Crashalytics developer tools error"

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

So, I have this code in my build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {

    manifestPlaceholders = [fabricKey: getFabricKey()]
}
def getFabricKey() {
    String path = System.getenv("HOME") + "/.apikeys/fabric_key.gradle"
    if (file(path).exists()) {
        return new File(path).text;
    } else {
        return "null";
    }
}
```

While in AndroidManifest.xml I have this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
            android:value="${fabricKey}" />
```

~/.apikeys/fabric_key.gradle exist on my machine. However, when I'm trying to build the project, "Crashalytics developer tools error" pops up. 
If I just place my key instead of ${fabricKey}, it works just fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Also, just to clarify things: What I want to achieve is, while having apikey removed from publically-accessible git repo, still be able to produce builds on my Jenkins server.

EDIT:

After running gradlew assembleDebug by-hand instead of IDE, I've found out this:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Crashlytics found an invalid API key: myValidApiKey .

(where myValidApiKey is a key that works when replacing ${fabricKey} with itself).

Comment: Sounds like the path is wrong, that error occurs whenever the fabric key can't be found. Have you tried adding some logging to the gradle method to see whether it thinks the file exists?

Comment: Yes, file is found, just checked it with additional logging. Updated OP accordingly with some new info.

Comment: Is there any trailing whitespace on myValidApiKey?

Comment: No, I've checked this twice already.

Comment: Okay. This is definetly something wrong either with code or with the file. I've re-done this to use environmental variable instead of reading from file. It works. I'd love to understand what was the reason of error in first place... but it works for now.

Comment: Isn't there extra newline character at the end of file?

Comment: No. File is 41 characters long, according to wc -c, as well as key is.